# Retrieving info from EC2 instances using AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

How can we retrieve system information in a newly deployed/provisioned linux EC2 instance using CDK and python in a Lambda function?

I'd like to know if it's possible to pull an environment variable or variables that is also defined in `/etc/environment.d/servervars.env`.

I'd like the values to become available inside my Lambda function. My current Lambda function knows the instance id.

Comment: Rather than thinking about how Lambda can access the instance, have you considered thinking about how the instance can make the information available _outside the instance_ (eg to the Lambda function)? For example, storing information in a tag associated with the instance, or pushing data to Amazon S3.

Comment: Accessing an instance is typically hard, unless the instance is running some form of server (eg a web server). Another option is to use Systems Manager to run a script on the instance to retrieve information, but it has a fairly high overhead to accomplish this.

Comment: I was actually thinking those things you mentioned earlier. I'm interested in what you wrote earlier, " For example, storing information in a tag associated with the instance". Can please you provide more information? Fyi, my existing lambda is triggered by CloudWatch and is triggered when an event is matched like EC2's RunInstances event.

Comment: What information do you want to obtain from the instance? Is it static information (never changing), or does it update at regular intervals? Is it information about the running application, or the instance itself? My idea was that an app on the instance can update the tag associated with the instance — think of it like metadata about something that is on the instance. Then, your Lambda function can simply look at the tags to discover the information. It's like wearing a name tag at a conference rather than everybody having to ask for your name every time.

Comment: That's a great idea. So it's the instance's responsibility to update it's own tag like us attendees taking care of our name tags rather than an external person putting tag at us. And yes, the information is static and it gets added during the provisioning of the instance. Which tool can be used by the instance to update its own tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the information is static and is added during the provisioning of the instances, you could add a line to the provisioning script:

```sh
MY_ID=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id --silent`

APPLICATION=payroll
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $MY_ID --tags Key=Application,Value=$APPLICATION
```

The AWS CLI requires AWS credentials to create the tags. This can be done by assigning an IAM Role to the instance with the `ec2:CreateTags` permission.